# Загрузка объекта unity3d, Instantiate, тормоза

Tags: unity3d, android, разработка-игр, ios

Ситуация следующая:
Unity3d.
При динамической загрузке объекта из префаба, если объект сложный, возникают лаги на мобильных устройствах.
При том лаги возникают, даже если разделить загрузку новой части карты корутином на отдельные объекты.

Может быть кто-нибудь знает методы борьбы с этим?

PS: самое обидное, что объекты абсолютно не высокополигональные, просто из-за отсутствия многопоточности в юнити загрузка же происходит в основном потоке(

Comment: тогда вынесите загрузку карт из UI-потока(основной поток андроид-приложения). Хз конечно как там у вас что.

Comment: Так в том вся и беда, что поток то в unity3d один, как бы то ни было ответ следующий:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/196413/gameobject-pool-to-avoid-performance-issues-in-ins.html

Но всё таки, вдруг есть какие-нибудь более удобные костыли, чем делать пулл всех используемых объектов, а потом их переиспользовать.

Answer (score 1):

Pool - это не костыль, а единственный верный подход для решения подобных задач. Просто для удобства создание из пула может выглядеть как-то так:

```
var instance = source.Spawn();
```

И выгрузка так:

```
instance.Recycle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас нет проблем с памятью, то можно загрузку этого тяжелого объекта делать на старте приложения, при необходимости включать и выключать (`SetActive()`) GameObject.